# Which AES mode does ASP.NET use for forms authentication?

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I need to verify ASP.NET forms authentication cookies in a NodeJS project. I know that for decryption, AES is being used with a 192-bit key. I looked at the [aspxauth](https://github.com/LeanKit-Labs/aspxauth) NPM package, but this is not working for my needs because it has `aes-256-cbc` hardcoded as the only supported algorithm. I tried editing its source code to use `aes-192-cbc` but it is failing to decrypt. Any idea what AES mode is used by default? This project is using ASP.NET WebForms on .NET 4.7.2 in .NETFramework 4.0 compatability mode.

Comment: Have you looked at the web.config - <machinekey>? This may help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/w8h3skw9(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: I'm having the same issue - I'm trying to use this for some clues (https://gist.github.com/akaNightmare/30985da516873f6d8d5b18b1877f325d), but still getting an error.
Did you figure it out @JamesFaix?

Comment: I did solve it, but I forget how, and I've since left the company I was working for, so I can't look at that codebase to recall.

Comment: Haha, no worries - thanks for getting back to me!
If the answer comes to you, please let me know ;)